# Extract XML data from nodes in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, xml-parsing

hey I'm trying to see what I'm doing wrong I hope you can help me
I get an **xml** response as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <LimitInfoHeader>
      <limitInfo>
        <current>50</current>
        <limit>5000000</limit>
        <type>API REQUESTS</type>
      </limitInfo>
    </LimitInfoHeader>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <queryResponse>
      <result>
        <done>true</done>
        <queryLocator xsi:nil="true"/>
        <records xsi:type="sf:Nodav">
          <sf:Id>a0S0E000000DMUg320</sf:Id>
          <sf:Name>Netta test 11</sf:Name>
        </records>
        <records xsi:type="sf:Nodav">
          <sf:Id>a0S0E000000DMUg321</sf:Id>
          <sf:Name>Netta test 32</sf:Name>
        </records>
        <size>2</size>
      </result>
    </queryResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and my code looks like:

```
Dim xmlhtp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Set records = xmlDoc.DocumentElement
Set lists = records.SelectNodes("//Envelope/Header/Body/queryResponse/result/records")
For Each listNode In lists.ChildNodes
    Debug.Print "---Email---"
    For Each fieldNode In listNode.ChildNodes
        Debug.Print "[" & fieldNode.BaseName & "] = [" & fieldNode.Text & "]"
    Next fieldNode
Next listNode

Set records = Nothing
```

now I get en error and all I want is to get the `sf:id` and the `sf:name` from all records can you help me fix my code please?

have a great day

Comment: Welcome to SO, I could not find a clear question, can you modify your post and define a question to solve? Please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) also read> [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: It's not XML. It's just a set of tags.

Comment: Where do you load the Document?  I would start by modifying the `Sub LoadDocument` found here: [A Beginner's Guide to the XML DOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468547.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented your original Xml did not "compile" (well-formed) so I edited that resource I hope it was a good edit because I have written code against it.

I have a problem with Xml namespaces because I do not know how to get a default namespace where I can skip a prefix.  So I am forced in my solution to always use a prefix even if I have to fake one.  The fake namespace `sf2` is added in my line beginning

`dom.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:sf='urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com' xmlns:sf2='urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com'`

I hope real Xml namespace expert can rewrite this answer better.  In the meantime this code works.  So I saved the file to a local drive.  Also, it is possible to totally drill in and grab the two `<records/>` elements directly but if you want a full path then see the commented out `Debug.Assert` lines

```
Option Explicit


Sub TestCoreLogic()
    Dim dom As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set dom = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    dom.Load "N:\xmlfile1.xml"
    Debug.Assert dom.parseError.ErrorCode = 0



    dom.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"


    dom.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:sf='urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com' xmlns:sf2='urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com' xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' "

    CoreLogic dom
End Sub
'
Function CoreLogic(ByVal xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60)

    Dim records As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
    Set records = xmlDoc.DocumentElement

    Dim lists As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList

    'Debug.Assert records.SelectNodes("//soapenv:Envelope").Length = 1
    'Debug.Assert records.SelectNodes("//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body").Length = 1
    'Debug.Assert records.SelectNodes("//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/sf2:queryResponse").Length = 1
    'Debug.Assert records.SelectNodes("//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/sf2:queryResponse/sf2:result").Length = 1
    '
    'Debug.Assert records.SelectNodes("//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/sf2:queryResponse/sf2:result/sf2:records").Length = 2
    'Set lists = records.SelectNodes("//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/sf2:queryResponse/sf2:result/sf2:records")

    Debug.Assert records.SelectNodes("//sf2:records").Length = 2
    Set lists = records.SelectNodes("//sf2:records")

    Dim listNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

    For Each listNode In lists
        Debug.Print "---Email---"

        Dim fieldNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
        For Each fieldNode In listNode.ChildNodes
            Debug.Print "[" & fieldNode.BaseName & "] = [" & fieldNode.Text & "]"
        Next fieldNode
    Next listNode

    Set records = Nothing
    Set lists = Nothing
    Set listNode = Nothing
    Set fieldNode = Nothing


End Function
```